Passing param to subquery Blaze persistence
How can I pass BranchId into SumQuantity?
Here my view:
enter image description here
This is subQueryProvider:
enter image description here
This is my query:
enter image description here
How can I pass the branchId to SumQuantity?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

You can inject optional parameters into your SubqueryProvider i.e.
public class SumQuantity extends SubqueryProvider {
  public SumQuantity(@MappingParameter("branchId") Long branchId) {}
  //..
}

You can then supply that to the EntityViewSetting via EntityViewSetting.create(MedicalSuppliesView.class).withOptionalParameter("branchId", 123L)
